# Android : How to make a radio button look like a toggle button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I add a Radio Button in my layout.

It is unchecked to begin with. And when I click on it , it becomes checked. But when i click on it again, it does not become unchecked again?

Comment: goto google.com and type `radibutton look like toggle, android` and search..

Comment: Please Google before you ask any question. We are ready to help you only if you have done your homework properly.

Answer (score 0):

`RadioButton` doesn't go from *checked-state* to *unchecked-state* on clicking. There is a simple solution for this. For your requirement, I would rather suggest you to use `ToggleButton`.

**i)** Add the below xml and 2 drawables([checked](http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/blueberry/32/radio-button_on.png) and [unchecked](http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/blueberry/32/radio-button_off.png))
    to your drawable-folder.

**toggle_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item   android:state_checked="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/checked" /> <!-- checked -->
    <item   android:state_checked="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" /> <!-- unchecked -->
</selector>
```

**ii)** Replace your RadioButton with ToggleButton.

**iii)** Set the background of your toggleButton to above xml-drawable.

Hope this helps.